# Fill listboxes from XML-file

Tags: c#, xml, listbox

I have an XML file and a ListBox that shows the data of the file.

The XML file is:

```
<students>
  <student>
    <id>1</id>
    <data>
      <subject name="Geopraphy" status="passed" />
      <subject name="History" status="passed" />
    </data>
  <student>
<students>
```

What I want to show in the listbox1 is the id of the student, and if selected, I want in another ListBox (listbox2) to be shown all the subjects of that student. This is the codeI have so far:

```
XmlDocument xm = new XmlDocument();
string list = "//id";

xm.Load("data.xml");
XmlNodeList Xn = xm.SelectNodes(list);

foreach (XmlNode xNode in Xn)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(xNode.InnerText);
}
```

How can I fill listbox2?

Comment: yes it is winform with 2 listboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    XmlNode nodes = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("/students/student[id={0}]/data", listBox1.SelectedItem));
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes.ChildNodes)
    {
         if (node.Attributes["status"].Value == "passed")
             listBox2.Items.Add(node.Attributes["name"].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I add a condition to this, for instance, if status=passed then show it in for instance listbox3?

Comment: Updated my answer check.

Comment: where in the code shall i put listBox2.Items.Clear();? so if i select new student, i don't want the items to be added under the previous items that are loaded in listbox2

Comment: never mind, i did it. i wanted to ask you another thing. How to add two items in the same row in the lisbox? listBox2.Items.Add(node.Attributes["name"].Value); + add surname

Comment: you can try `listBox2.Items.Add(node.Attributes["name"].Value + "something");`

Comment: thanks, sorry for bothering you, how can i list attribute name of subject into another listbox3 for the selected id, and then add condition, if the selected id from listbox1 and selected subject name, then list into listbox4 all the statuses for that user of that subject name?

Comment: listbox1 will list all students id, when selected, list all the subjects in listbox2, when selected subject, list in listbox3 if status of that subject

Answer (score 2):

First - I suggest you to use Linq to Xml for parsing xml (or Xml Serialization if possible). Second - I suggest to create class which will hold student and subject data:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; } // enum or boolean is better
}
```

Then parse students from xml and map them to UI instead of working with xml from UI:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("students.xml");
var students = xdoc.Root.Elements("student")
                   .Select(st => new Student {
                       Id = (int)st.Element("id"),
                       Subjects = st.Element("data")
                                    .Elements("subject")
                                    .Select(s => new Subject {
                                        Name = (string)s.Attribute("name"),
                                        Status = (string)s.Attribute("status")
                                     }).ToList()
                    }).ToList();
```

Then you can bind students to listbox:

```
 listBox1.DisplayMember = "Id";
 listBox1.DataSource = students;
```

And display subjects in listbox2 when selected student changed:

```
 listBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";
 listBox2.DataSource = selectedStudent.Subjects;
```

Comment: What is `selectedStudent` in this context?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried with xpath?

```
/students/student[@id=1]/data/subject
```

Where 1 is the the value selected in listbox1

You can see an example in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx(v=vs.110).aspx

EDITED: Added listbox1_selectedIndex event handled

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1) {
            string path = String.Concat("/students/student[@id=", listBox1.SelectedItem, "]/data/subject");
            FillListbox2(xm, path);
        }
    }
```

In your code you'll need to move the XDocument as a property in the form

Comment: Yes, but I need selected id from the listbox1, and how will be the code in listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged ?

Comment: Edited the response to answer your comment

Comment: what about FillLisbox2?

Comment: I think the below example, posted by @Pragnesh Khalas would be useful. By using my xpath route you only need to iterate over the XmlNodeList returned by SelectNodes.
What attribute do you want to add to listBox: name or status?

Answer (score 0):

I think below will help you

```
       XmlDocument xm = new XmlDocument();
        string list = "//data";
        xm.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
        XmlNodeList Xn = xm.SelectNodes(list);
        foreach (XmlNode xNode in Xn)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(xNode.ChildNodes[0].Name.InnerText);
        }
```